# Change set deployment fails

Tags: deployment, change-set

My org is new and was activated (from a trial org a week ago).
Most of the code in production was written when the org was still in Trial. Production test coverage is 79%.

I'm trying to deploy a change set from the sandbox, with 83% coverage.
In Production, deployment validation fails because of 63% coverage but there is no error or exception in the deployment log.

This org had a related issue a couple of days ago, where the change sets where not visible in Production (root cause was the NA3 split).

Please help...

Comment: Start by running all tests in PROD (without the changeset) and see if you can update your tests in sandbox to cover the missing lines; otherwise issue could be testmethod that is using seeAllData=true (or is at V23 or less) so sandbox results are not predictive

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I forgot to put @isTest for one method although the class did have it

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer.  Please mark this as the solution to close the question.